# Reference request for studying on Fiber bundles

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

I am looking for some material (e.g. references, books, notes) to get started with Fiber bundles and vector bundles. Can someone help me? 
Thanks.

Comment: what have you already studied?

Comment: look at http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/husemoller

Comment: @JamesS.Cook I have studied Smooth Manifolds, Riemannian and Pseudo Riemannian geometry, Lie groups and Lie algebra and ...

Comment: @janmarqz Thanks, but I am looking for a newer books or notes.

Comment: Perhaps the book Fibre Bundles by Dale Husemöller